# How to test the data specific stress testing?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, jmeter, database-performance, stress-testing

In my application there are hierarchy of lead user & child users i.e one lead user has multiple child users.
Lead user can view all the records of all the child users (i.e. suppose one lead user have four child users & each contains one record then total records under lead users are four).

So my question is how to perform the data specific stress testing i.e. how to test, for how much maximum data application get supported.

Can we automate this?
Please suggest any tool or with the help of JMETER we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- You have list of lead user
- For each lead user you have list of child user
- You want to iterate over each lead

  - For each lead user, you want to iterate over each child user

Following is one way you could proceed. A typical jmeter plan will look like this

- CSV data config ( http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config )

  - Your csv will have list of lead user and the path to the child csv list
- Read the child list using csvread function ( CSVRead">http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#_CSVRead )

  - Iterate over all child user and do whatever operation you need to do.